# How to have the scaffold to generate another partial view template file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, customization, scaffold

I'm trying to customize my **scaffold generator**, and I would like to have a new **partial** for the view in the same directory, in particular `_item` to be called both **inside index and show**. I can get all the templates but I'm not able to generate this file through

```
rails g scaffold foo name:string
```

I tried to put _item.erb in `/lib/templates/erb/scaffold/` (together with the other files) but it is ignored- Does anybody have a clue?

I use ruby on rails 3, but please let me know if the solution is valid for rails 2 as well.
I also use simple_form (thus I already have the _form partial), but I think the solution should be valid even without it.

Comment: You shall dive in this code: https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found it.

It is hardcoded. You can change it:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb

```
  def available_views
    %w(index edit show new _form)
  end
```

In my index template I did like this:

```
        <thead id="thead_js">
        <%%= render 'thead' %>

        <!-- CUT TO _thead.html.erb -->
        <tr>
            <% for attribute in attributes -%>
                <th><%%= sortable( <%= attribute.name %>, <%= attribute.human_name %> ) %></th>
            <% end %>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- END CUT TO -->

    </thead>
```

Then, just created a rake task that reads that comment and create the new files.

Ugly but effective.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I'll definitely find the time to implement it my way.

Answer (score 15):

I came across this question hoping to find an answer as the default rails scaffold generator is pretty crippled if you want to:

1. Refactor your scaffold views or make use of partials
2. Use controller and view inheritance
3. Support additional controller actions and their views
4. Support a mix of template engines, erb, haml, slim, jbuilder, prawn etc

Alas, I rolled up my sleeves and figured out how to make rails scaffold generator support the above requirements which I make use of on my current project.

If you want full control over your scaffold templates when you type `rails g scaffold Foo ...` then read on!

### The Problem

The default rails scaffold generator is template engine specific AND hard codes a fixed set of view files that it looks for.

### The Solution

Use a custom generator and wire it up to the scaffold template generation.

I have included a generator below that looks in `lib/templates/scaffold` and will generate scaffold views for ALL files found there including templates, partials and sub-directories regardless of the template engine.

IMO this *should* be the default rails behaviour instead of us having to jump through hoops like this..

### Implementation

Do the following:

1. Put whatever templates or partials you want created when scaffolding into `lib/templates/scaffold`. Notice there is no `erb` subdirectory !!
2. Configure the generator template engine for your project as shown below
3. Add my custom view generator (included below)

#### Rails 4 generator configuration:

```
# config/initializers/generators.rb
Rails.application.config.generators do |g|
  # ...
  g.template_engine :all
  g.fallbacks[:all] = :erb # or haml/slim etc
end
```

#### Rails 3 generator configuration:

```
# config/application.rb
config.generators do |g|
  # ...
  g.template_engine :all
  g.fallbacks[:all] = :erb # or haml/slim etc
end
```

#### The custom scaffold generator:

```
# lib/generators/all/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb
require 'rails/generators/named_base'
require 'rails/generators/resource_helpers'

module All # :nodoc:
  module Generators # :nodoc:
    class ScaffoldGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase # :nodoc:
      include Rails::Generators::ResourceHelpers

      source_root File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'templates', 'scaffold', File::SEPARATOR)

      argument :attributes, type: :array, default: [], banner: "field:type field:type"

      def create_root_folder
        empty_directory File.join("app/views", controller_file_path)
      end

      def copy_view_files
        available_views.each do |view|
          template view, File.join("app/views", controller_file_path, view)
        end
      end

    protected
      def available_views
        # use all template files contained in source_root ie 'lib/templates/scaffold/**/*'
        base = self.class.source_root
        base_len = base.length
        Dir[File.join(base, '**', '*')].select { |f| File.file?(f) }.map{|f| f[base_len..-1]}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### Caveats

No warranty offered :)

I hope this helps others who want to refactor their scaffold views with partials and support multiple template engines.

Comment: Can't we just `monkey patch` the `ScaffoldGenerator` class?

Comment: @RSK. The generator above is a monkey patch, it replaces the scaffold generator class with one that is useful.  Since it is not just a matter of overriding a function or two in the original class (note the ``source_root`` and ``argument`` calls in the class definition, which are done differently in the original class effectively damage the original class from that point on). Complete class replacement in this case is cleaner and simpler.

Comment: here we defined all new `All` template engine right?, why can't we patch the `available_views` method in `Erb::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator`

Comment: @RSK well look at my code above, it clearly does more than overriding a single method. If you can't read the full class definition and see that there are other required methods to be defined so that it works as I have described and class level method calls (source_root and argument need to be called) plus my prior explanation to you already above I can't really help you. If you think you have a one liner that works then post an answer. I know the code above works and does what I have described. Your one liner will affect generator but it won't do what I have described.

Comment: This is still working for me in Rails 5, big thanks for this one!

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is hardcoded into scaffold g. What I did was to create a rake task that adds more files.