# Copy additional file with default rails scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator, scaffold

I customized my scaffold files (view and controller). But by default it copies only the standard files like:

- _form.html.erb
- edit.html.erb
- index.html.erb
- new.html.erb
- show.html.erb

but I've to copy (and render) additional files like a "_list.html.erb" or something like "index.js.erb"

How would be the best way to do this, without creating an own generator? I'd like to use the standard rails scaffold.

thanks for help!

Comment: I worked out how to do exactly what you want so that it works with the standard scaffold generation. The answer is here: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/18533215/2238268>