# Custom erb generator called from scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, scaffold

I am looking to not only customise my erb scaffold templates but also to add new templates.

In `ScaffoldGenerator < Erb::Generators::Base` I can see there there is a way to provide additional templates in `%w(index edit show new _form)`.

So I have created a custom erb generator and templates directory in my application in `lib/generators/erb/scaffold/`.

However when I run `rails g scaffold Something`, my custom generator is not picked up by via `scaffold_controller`. Does this mean I need to provide a custom `scaffold` generator to use a custom `scaffold_controller` generator just so it can then use my `erb` generator?

I can also see the scaffold argument:

```
ScaffoldController options:
  -e, [--template-engine=NAME]  # Template engine to be invoked
                                # Default: erb
```

Am I able to provide my erb generator as the template engine to be used?

(Using Rails 4)

Comment: Pretty much answers my question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696954/how-to-have-the-scaffold-to-generate-another-partial-view-template-file?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

`lib/templates/erb/scaffold` is the correct path for rails scaffold.

Just in case...

model goes in `/lib/templates/active_record/model/model.rb`

controller goes in `/lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb`